# Reset autoincrement in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, auto-increment, identity-column

I created a primary key to be autoincrement.

- I added two rows: `ID=1, ID=2`
- I deleted these two rows.
- I added a new row, but the new row's ID was: `ID=3`

How can I reset or restart the autoincrement to 1?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If you use the [`DBCC CHECKIDENT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx) command:

```
 DBCC CHECKIDENT ("YourTableNameHere", RESEED, 1);
```

But **use with CAUTION!** - this will just reset the `IDENTITY` to 1 - so your next inserts will get values 1, then 2, and then 3 --> and you'll have a clash with your pre-existing value of 3 here!

`IDENTITY` just dishes out numbers in consecutive order - it does **NOT** in any way make sure there are no conflicts!  If you already have values - do **not** reseed back to a lower value!

Comment: I forgot to tell, I'm using Management Studio, so I want to reseed it with the Management Studio

Comment: @victorio: just open a new query window and execute this T-SQL command!

Comment: I am using SQL server 2008 and to reset to value 1 I have to put 0 on the last parameter, then: DBCC CHECKIDENT ("YourTableNameHere", RESEED, 0);

Answer (score 21):

I'm using **SQL Server 2012** and the `DBCC CHECKIDENT ("YourTableNameHere", RESEED, 1)` causes a value of `2` on the very next insert.

So for SQL Server 2012, change the `1` to `0` to get a value of `1` for your next record insert:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ("YourTableNameHere", RESEED, 0);  -- value will be 1 for the next record insert
```