# what is the best way to insert multiple rows to production table in sql

Tags: sql, t-sql, sqltransaction

I want to know what is the best practice to insert multiple rows from a source table into a destination table. **Both** source and destination tables are on a production database meaning delete or update transactions are being performed 24/7 on the tables. Also the destination table has an auto_incremented column which means if a Rollback transaction executes, the Rollback does not decrement the auto incremented column - find details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758625/mysql-auto-increment-columns-on-transaction-commit-and-rollback)

```
BEGIN TRY 
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    Insert (col1,col2,col3) into destinationTable
    select col1,col2,col3 from sourceTable
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
    PRINT 'TRANSACTION COMMITTED'
END TRY


BEGIN CATCH
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
      PRINT 'TRANSACTION ROLLED BACK'  
END CATCH
```

Comment: Have a look at bulk insert.

Comment: Of course this is the best way. Who cares about gaps in a sequence?

Comment: What number of records are you talking about? What is the problem with your approach? Have you considered (or do you need to) [reset the auto increment value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858062/reset-autoincrement-in-microsoft-sql-server-2008-r2)

Comment: If you wish to have records from the `Source Table` to the `Destination table` as an when the data gets inserted into the `Source` then you can make use of the `Trigger`.

Comment: If speed is the issue here (i'm not quite sure what the problem is with skipping rows) then have you considered the SWITCH TO statement

      ALTER TABLE [SOURCETABLE]
  SWITCH TO [DESTINATION TABLE]

It does not hit the logs so it is a very fast way of transferring data between tables. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41348523/how-does-alter-table-switch-works-on-sql-server